# Bass booster with op-amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, schematics

I've found this schematics:
[image]

([link](http://seanm.ca/stomp/bassbooster.html))

On the page they say "It can boost by 14dB" (they mean that amplifier can boost bass by 14dB). But now I'm little confused - is the circuit configured to boost bass by 14dB or must I change something to boost it by 14dB ?

How can I calculate that?

Thanks :)

Comment: The calculation itself is a bit complicated. The circuit should already be set to have that gain. Basically what you need to do is calculate the gain of the op-amps and then combine it by applying the gain of the right op-amp to the output of the left op-amp. After that you have frequency characteristics that need to be calculated too, but I'm not experienced enough to comment on how to calculate that.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: Actually the calculations are pretty simple.  The left opamps is just a unity gain buffer except for very high frequencies which is reduces.  The 22kOhm resistor in series with the second opamp minus input does nothing.  That leaves a single inverting opamp stage.  Ignore the capacitor for low frequencies and pretend it's shorted for high frequencies.  Pretty simple when you look at it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there is a potentiometer, a variable resistor that can be regulated to give a gain on the lower frequencies that can go up to 14 dB, depending on the position of the cursor in the 50K resistor.

Since the 47n capacitance bypasses the higher frequencies, you should have the least bass amplification with the cursor in the rightmost position:

```
(22+47)/(50+22) ~= 1
```

and the maximum amplification for the leftmost position:

```
(50+47+22)/22 ~= 5
```

And this is for the lowest signals; since any signal is cut due to the lower gain given by the 47n bypass capacitor, you can (depending on the frequencies that you consider) have that gain, but basically it gives you a 5-factor regulation.

Comment: Could you please explain calculations to me ? I mean, which values (of what parts) are you using and why ? Maybe you know of some good website on that topic? Let's say, e.g. if I set potentiometer to 19k, how do I calculate gain ? Thanks :)

Comment: The gain should be 20log(Sout/Sin), in which in this case S represent the rate between the low-frequency signal and the high frequency signal.

Answer (score 3):

That circuit will leave the amplitude of high frequency signals about as they are.  Depending on how the tone control is set, it can boost the low frequencies from about 0 db (leaves them as is) to about 15 dB.

Comment: And what do you mean by tone control ? Maybe that 50k potentiometer ?

Comment: @xx77aBs: Yes, the pot is a tone control.  At one end you get flat response, at the other end the bass is boosted by about 15 dB.